# Set maxlength input JQuery fails

Tags: jquery, html

I want to set the `maxlength` attribute for an `input[type='text']` using JQuery as users typing. So when the `input[type='text']` has reached the max value it will not continue.

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#nama').keyup(function(){
        if(check($('input#username'),5)){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            $('input#username').val($(this).val());
        }
    });

    function check(text,max){
        if(text.length > 5){
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is the `input[type='text']` continued to be filled although it has reached the max value

Answer (score 0):

Because first parameter of `check` function is `string` and you are passing DOM object. While calling function `check` pass value of `input` instead of passing complete object. Consider following:

```
check($('input#username').val(),5)
                         ^^^^^^ ===> //Calling function pass value
```

Complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#nama').keyup(function(){
        if(check($('input#username').val(),5)){ //updated here
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            $('input#username').val($(this).val());
        }
    });

    function check(text,max){
        if(text.length > 5){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh yes. That was stupid error. I checked the string instead of value of `input[type='text']` Thank you very much

Comment: I hope your problem i solved. Please next don't use SO for posting debuging help until its necessary. You can accept answer. Before posting question learn proper debugging script. Enjoy scripting.

Comment: I'm sorry but could I give another question. When the `input[type='text']` does not reached the max value yet, it is editable but when it has reached it's not editable anymore although I've already emptied the triggering  `input#nama` . Could you show me how to fix it?